# Testing RxJS using TestScheduler with Promises and angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, reactjs, rxjs

I'm having a small issue using RxJS and Angular (not Angular 2) that I'm sure indicates I'm just doing something wrong, but I'm not sure exactly what.

I have a function that creates an rx.Observable stream that I would like to test.  A simplified version of the function is below:

```js
ResourceCollection.prototype.rxFetch = function() {
    var scheduler = this.injectedScheduler;

    var result = functionThatReturnsAnObservable(theseParams).concatMap(function(items) {
        var promises = _.map(readFromExternal(items), function(promise) {
            // results of this promise should be ignored
            return Rx.Observable.fromPromise(promise, scheduler);
        });
        promises = promises.concat(_.map(items, function(item) {
            // callEvent returns EventResult, these values should be passed on
            return Rx.Observable.fromPromise(callEvent(item), scheduler);
        }));
        return promises;
    }).concatMap(function(x) { return x; }).filter(function(res) {
        return (res instanceOf EventResult);
    }).toArray();

    return result;
});
```

My test function looks like this:

```js
describe('query', function() {
  var customers;
  var scheduler;

  beforeEach(function() {
      scheduler = new Rx.TestScheduler();
            
      customers = new ResourceCollection({
          url: '/api/customers',
          keyName: 'CustomerId',
          globalActions: {
              rxQuery: { method: 'GET', isArray: true }
          }
      });
      $httpBackend.whenGET('/api/customers/rxQuery').
  respond(function() {
          return [200, [
              { CustomerId: 1, Name: 'Brian', Region: 'North' },
              { CustomerId: 2, Name: 'Ravi', Region: 'East' },
              { CustomerId: 3, Name: 'Ritch', Region: 'East' },
              { CustomerId: 4, Name: 'Jeff', Region: 'West' },
              { CustomerId: 5, Name: 'Brandon', Region: 'West' }
          ]];
      });
  });
      
  it('rxFetch customers', function(done) {
    var vals;
    customers.injectedScheduler = scheduler
    var result = customers.rxFetch();
            
    result.subscribe(function(values) {
        vals = values;
    });
            
    $httpBackend.flush();
    
    // my question is here - what can I do to get rid of this loop?
    while (vals == null) {
        scheduler.advanceBy(100);
        $rootScope.$apply();
    }
            
    scheduler.start();

    expect(vals.length).toEqual(5);
    expect(vals[0]).toBe(customers[0]);
    done();
  });
      
});
```

The issue is a simple one - while the while loop in the test is in there, the test will produce the correct results (which is an array that contains the results of all the callEvent functions).  Replace the while loop with a scheduler.scheduleAbsolute (or some other such call) combined with a $rootScope.$apply, and only one of the promises from the callEvent function will complete.  Call it twice, and two of them will complete, etc (hence the while loop).

But the while loop is pretty ugly - and I'm sure there has to be an cleaner way to get this test to pass.  Many thanks to anyone who can point me in the correct direction.

Comment: I'd try to split this test. From look of it you are trying to test that `rxFetch` will call three other functions (`functionThatReturnsAnObservable`, `readFromExternal` and `callEvent` ) and will successfully combine they result in case of success. So I'd simply mock all  three of them, and check if they were called with correct params, and return pre-resolved promises. Then you'd have to create a separate test for each of those functions.

Comment: That also doesn't quite work.  I replaced the function calls with pre-resolved items using var defer = $q.defer() and defer.resolve(item) and that doesn't quite work - the scheduler needs to be thunked and $rootScope.$apply() still needs to be called once for every promise I create this way.  I was assuming it was an angular / rx scheduler issue and was hoping others may know of a way to inject something into the scheduler to simulate the "run loop".